# How does the following program work?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SQR(x) (x*x)
int main(){
int a;
a= SQR(3-4);
printf("%d",a);
return 0;
}
```

Output :-13

How does the macro function work here to give the output as -13?

Comment: It works as follows: `3-4*3-4`.To get correct answer,use `#define SQR(x) ((x)*(x))`

Comment: It evaluates to `3-4*3-4=3-16=-13`.

Comment: @Rohan wouldn't it be 3-12-4 = -9-4?

Comment: @Mauren: What's the difference? `+` and `-` have same precedence.

Comment: @Rohan surely they do, I was just wondering the order in which the calculations take place.

Answer (score 1):

The expression inside `SQR` gets `3-4*3-4`, and given the precendence of operators, gives you that result. This is a common mistake in macros. In principle, every argument should be surrounded with parentheses, if it involves some calculation:

```
#define SQR(x) ((x)*(x))
```

You'll get the expected result.